# Auto cropping scanned document or photo

Tags: distortion, perspective

I usually take a picture of bill or receipt using my mobile phone and store it in a computer. Is there any desktop or Web-based software which can straighten the photo of a paper and flatten it? For example I want to create a rectangular image without any distortion from this image.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is really on-topic, but there are a number of phone apps which do just what you want. I use an app called Genius Scan on my iPhone.

Comment: Right, even cam scanner does it for Android but I need a desktop app or web based solution

Comment: This should be moved to stackoverflow, if really an automatic solution is/was required.

Comment: Recent versions of Hugin, which is primarily a panorama-stitching program, are pretty good at automatically identifying horizontal and vertical control points. That might be a starting point for a solution. http://hugin.sourceforge.net/ http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/perspective/en.shtml

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**.  This kind of distortion is known as "keyhole" or "perspective" distortion.  Many commercial image processing programs include capabilities to correct it.  An illustrated workflow using [the GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) (a free download) is illustrated at http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/gimp/ss/perspective.htm.

Comment: The title suggests that an automatic approach is sought. This one requires manual intervention.

Comment: Yes, @Una, the title may suggest that, but the question seems to leave it open.  Before voting (or suggesting) to close you should at least request a verification from the OP on that point.  In fact, why would automatic solutions be off topic here, anyway?

Comment: I haven't, and I suspect the OP isn't around anymore. I don't believe that this is off topic. The reason, why I would suggest moving it to SO, is that it will get answered there.

Comment: I'm curious why you think this would get answered over on SO, and not get closed the moment it lands? This is not a programming, language, or platform question...its a software question at worst, and still a photography question at best. Cropping and distortion correction are most definitely within the realm of on-topic here, and I think whuber has offered a decent starting point in his answer. Combined with a little Scriot-Fu, and this could probably be automated quite easily.